# how to add thead to my grid in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have my grid like this in jquery

```
success: function(result) {
    $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td>' + result.FileName + '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
}
```

now i want to add thead to MyGrid to which i need to add style property and inside thead i also need to add tr having style property. as like

```
 <thead style=""><tr style=""></tr></thead>
```

through jquery

also i need to remove that thead in another jquery function. so could you please provide me how to add thead and delete that thead in jquery which has tr inside it.

thanks,
michaeld

Comment: What purpose do the empty style properties serve?

Comment: you can see in my tbody i have remove so once remove is clicked i don't want styles added that's why!

Comment: I can't work out what you'retrying to say there. You realize that `<thead style=""><tr style=""></tr></thead>` is identical to `<thead><tr></tr></thead>`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you create the `thead`:

```
$('#MyGrid').append(
    $('<thead />').addClass('headerrow').append(
        $('<tr />').addClass('grouprow')
    )
)
```

Do you actually need to remove, or would hiding it be ok? If you're happy to hide it:

```
$('#MyGrid thead').hide();
```

Comment: thnx eric, but i didn't get "your and go " properties and their values .also does the tr would be inside thead?

Comment: The tr is inside the thead. The `your` and `go` properties were showing you where the css properties go. I've edited my answer

Comment: actually i have modified it into this way , what i have is as <thead styleclass="headerrow" ><tr styleclass="grouprow"></tr></thead> can you modify the answer to get this. thnx.

Comment: @michael: `styleclass` isn't a valid HTML attribute... Did you mean `class`?

Comment: yes only class property taking string type. sry for typo error

Answer (score 0):

```
function addtHead(table){
    var thead = jQuery("<thead></thead>");
    thead.attr('style','<your style goes here>');
    thead.attr('id', 'thead');
    var tr = jQuery("<tr></tr>");
    /*......Add columns here.........*/
    thead.append(tr);
    table.append(thead);
}

function removeThead(table){
    table.find('thead').remove();
}
```

Usage:

```
success: function(result) {

  $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td>' + result.FileName + '</a></td><td>
```

Remove');
       addThead($('#MyGrid tbody'));

```
}
/*.. where you need to remove the thead...*/
removeThead($('#MyGrid tbody'));
```